# Problemas con ciclo for en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tomando un conjunto de imágenes y un conjunto (hijo) que sera fondo negro que lo topara un `60%`. El problema es que me sale el error:

> galeria.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
> at HTMLDivElement.

Aquí esta mi código:

```
let descriptor = document.querySelectorAll(".container-description"),
  imagenes = document.querySelectorAll(".litlle, .large, .big");

for(var i =0;i < imagenes.length ;i++){
    imagenes[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        for(var j = 0; j < descriptor.length ;j++){
            descriptor[j].style.height = "60%";
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Es porque `.style` espera un atributo y valor como `descriptor[j].style.color= "blue"` [Element.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

Comment: Acabo de corregir

Answer (score 1):

Cuando recorras un array y uses como condición de parada una condición que evalue `length` recuerda que los elementos iterables (como arrays) comienzan su indexación en cero, por lo tanto la condición debe de ser con el operador de menor que `<`:

```
j< descriptor.length
```

Sin usar el operador de menor o igual `<=` o haciendo `j< descriptor.length-1`, esto porque por ejemplo si tienes 4 elementos guardados en una variable llamada `miArray`, sus indices serían 0,1,2,3. Si haces `miArray[miArra.length]` equivaldría a `miArray[4]` lo cual no corresponde a ningún indice dentro de tu array.

Lo que está ocurriendo en tu código es que estas accediendo a un elemento fuera del array `descriptor`, esto tira un valor de `undefined` y cuando tratas de acceder la propiedad de `style` en el obtienes tu error de `Cannot read property 'style' of undefined at HTMLDivElement`.

Te lo ilustro con este ejemplo:

```js
const miArray = ["pato", "perro", "rana", "gato"];

function correcto() {
  for (let i = 0; i < miArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(`miArray[${i}]=${miArray[i]}`);
  }
}

function incorrecto() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= miArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(`miArray[${i}]=${miArray[i]}`);
  }
}
console.log("Manera Correcta:");
correcto();
console.log("Manera Incorrecta(accediendo elemento fuera de array, undefined):");
incorrecto();

//También puedes usar forEach para recorrer un objeto iterable

function conForEach() {
  miArray.forEach((elemento, indice) => {
    console.log(`miArray[${indice}]=${elemento}`);
  })
}
console.log("Utilizando forEach:");
conForEach();
```

Comment: Amigo estoy agradecido por la información a que tienes razón, más en mi código siempre pongo un -1 a la condición,  justamente ahora no me sale ningún error sino que al hacer click todos los elementos se cubren con el fondo negro

Comment: Con mucho gusto, si la información te es útil y resuelve tu problema te invito a marcar la respuesta como acertada para que cualquier otro usuario que tenga el mismo problema que tú pueda encontrar la solución a su problema.

Comment: Espera ¿Tienes otro problema relacionado a tu pregunta?

Comment: Si, cuando doy click en algún elemento todo los fondos que coloque se activan, y solo quiero que se ejecute el que yo este presionando

Comment: Ya que esta pregunta está relacionada al ciclo for y el error que describiste; y el problema que tienes a ahora no está relacionado a esto te recomiendo abrir una nueva pregunta donde describas el nuevo problema y describas el comportamiento esperado. Yo estaré atento a tu pregunta en el transcurso del día.

Comment: Amigo ya publique